# Google Forms quiz submit ONLY when ALL correct

Tags: google-forms

I would like to use Google Forms to create a simple 5 question multiple choice quiz.

When the user has selected their answers and clicked `Submit` I would like to display immediate feedback on the same page. They should not be able to proceed until all of the answers are correct.

So let's say they answer 1 - 4 correct but 5 is incorrect, I'd like to display message along the lines of;

> Are you sure? Try again.

Once they select the correct answer for number 5, they can then proceed to submit the form and the results are recorded as normal.

Basically, I don't want to record the results until **all** of the questions have been answered correctly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

**What you are asking for, cannot be achieved using Google Forms.**

*(You could probably try using GAS but that is a completely different "ball game")*

## As an alternative

You could achieve what you ask for but only on a per question/section basis.

Please have a look at this [TEST FORM](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdWJ5n3PN5xhZkP8G9fidjyuMCHPptnS6sz40Ov_JHtorE2gw/viewform?usp=sf_link) I prepared for you.

Comment: Did you have a look at the form? Would this suit your needs?

Comment: I was wanting to do something similar. This is perfect, how did you do it?

Comment: _"I was wanting to do something similar"_. @ctrl-alt-delor You would need to explain the "similar" part. Could have many interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the answer of @marikamitsos. Here is how to do it.

It does not work with all question types. It does work with simple multi-choice, but not checkbox.

- Create a quiz with sections, one answer per section.
- Add a section after each question. I will call this the review section. In it add feedback.
- For each question enable "goto section based on answer", change the default option for correct answers, so that it goes to the next section.

## For and against

- For: it works.
- Against: It is error prone, hard work, see  [https://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Estorm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf)
- Possible mitigation: maybe a google-app-script can be written, that takes a compatible quiz and outputs a quiz of this type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. At the bottom of each question, click the 3 dots, then click response validation. See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8V_qnmedxY