# It it possible for a google forms-quiz to display results immediately?

Tags: google-forms

I have some quizzes for students. I want them to the the results immediately. I can configure it so that students can see there results immediately after submitting. However it would be good if it could give them the feedback after each question. How can I do this?

---

I would be happy to find a non-forms answer, as long as it is for google web-apps (as this is what we use at work).

Comment: I guess you already solved this...

Comment: @marikamitsos. No that is why I asked. If I had an answer, then I would add it.

Comment: _"No that is why I asked"_ Correct! :) Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3pfA.png) what you are looking for? Let me know so I can turn it to a proper answer.

Comment: I have already done that, it give the results **after** submisison.

Comment: So what do you mean by _"it would be good if it could give them the feedback after each question"_? Google forms are only aware of the answers **only and only after** a form is submitted.

Comment: Even if there is a way to show the feedback after each question. What is the point of a quiz? One would just see the correct answers and never submit the form.

Comment: I found an answer. It was inspired by this answer https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/137775/11766 (you will never guess who write it).  With a bit of experimenting I discovered how to do it. It is horrendous. Any one thinking of doing it should read goto considered harmful.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/137763/11766

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106992/discussion-between-marikamitsos-and-ctrl-alt-delor).